# Redshift for ARM, Arch Linux

Tags: pi-3, archlinux, xorg

I have an RPi 3b running Arch Linux.

I'm attempting to run Redshift:

```
redshift -O 3300
```

The output is:

```
Gamma ramp size too small: 0
Failed to start adjustment method randr.
Trying next method...
Using method 'vidmode'.
```

Nothing happens! The [Arch Arm Wiki](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3) says:

> The X.org driver for Raspberry Pi can be installed with the
> xf86-video-fbdev or xf86-video-fbturbo-git package.

Both are installed, I've alternated removing and reinstall them. No luck.
Any advice? Redshift has become essential these days. :D

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the experimental OpenGL driver to run Redshift. First, upgrade to latest kernel/firmware:

```
rpi-update
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then, run `raspi-config`, go to Advanced Settings and enable the experimental OpenGL driver. Reboot and try running Redshift again.

Edit: sorry, I completely overlooked the Arch Linux. Hopefully, you still have `rpi-update` and `raspi-config` on it.

Comment: I do not! There appears to be some forks for arch, but they look pretty suspect. Any recommended ways of enabling the driver or rasp-config within Arch? It did work within Raspbian using the method you described.

Comment: @Goodroot Sorry, I have no experience with Arch. AFAIK Raspbian is the only officially supported OS on RPi, everything else is "community effort". The moment you ditch Raspbian, you lose that support, at which point you may as well ditch the RPi and go for a cheaper and more powerful board.

Comment: This seems to be outdated; the experimental OpenGL driver is not available in raspi-config anymore.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig Is the original issue still present in the latest ArchLinux?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I am not using Arch, but raspian. And the issue is still present, yes.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
ddcutil setvcp 10 50
ddcutil setvcp 12 50
```